# Firebase snapshot to json flutter model

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter

Hello i am trying to get data from a firebase database and save it in a model class
exactly the same way as you do for http json
so this is my class model

```
UsersModel usersModelFromJson(String str) => UsersModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class UsersModel {
    String age;
    String heigth;
    String userid;
    String username;
    String weigth;

    UsersModel({
        this.age,
        this.heigth,
        this.userid,
        this.username,
        this.weigth,
    });

    factory UsersModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) => UsersModel(
        age: json["age"],
        heigth: json["heigth"],
        userid: json["userid"],
        username: json["username"],
        weigth: json["weigth"],
    );
```

and this is how i try to get the data

```
Future obtenerDatos(userid) async {
  var bd = dB.child('users').child(userid).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
    values.forEach((key, values) {

      return UsersModel.fromJson(values);
    });
  }
```

i get this error

```
`Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`
```

i have tried everything i can prit it as json but i dont understand why i cant save it to the model class i have 2 days with the same problem please help me

Comment: I can't test your code but you probably have to update your fromJson method like this `factory UsersModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) `

Comment: Already tried . i have the same problem 
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: At which line the error occurs? Maybe you can declare values with `Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;` instead ?
The DataSnapshot value is of type Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line in obtenerDatos : `Map<String, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;`

To: `Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;`

The error happens because your fromjson method expects map of the type `<dynamic, dynamic>` and you mapped the response like `<String, dynamic>`

Comment: The error is in the foreach .. i got fixed using your answer and removing the foreach but in that way i cant save the values in the model